# Why isn't printing if i press enter?

Tags: java, string

Here is a problem in hackerrank. I am a noob in java so am facing a problem. In the code logic if i  press enter means `\n` `nextLine()` will get it and will print number 1 but if I press enter it does print 1 but when I input a string it will print all the previous number why?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 1;

        while (input.hasNext()) {
            String s = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(count + " " + s);
            count++;
        }

        input.close();
    }
}
```

My current result is:

```
(enter)//input
//no output
(enter)//input
//no output
(enter)//input
//no output
Hello World! //input
1
2
3
4 Hello World!//output
```

But shouldn't it be like

```
(enter)//input
1 //output
(enter)//input
2 //output
(enter)//input
3 //output
Hello World!//input
4 Hello World! //output
```

Comment: Where are you running this code?

Comment: Don't mix `hasNext` with `nextLine`. If I use `hasNextLine` the program works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `input.hasNext()` does not include an empty new line. You should change it to `input.hasNextLine()` to produce the desired effects, such as in the following:

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 1;

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String s = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(count + " " + s);
            count++;
        }

        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: As a general recommendation (while in this code example it's probably not a big deal, but builds bad habits), you shouldn't `close` the `Scanner` which is reading from the `System.in`, because it will also close `System.in`, which is something your probably never really want to do. Just saying